# clojure.core: . operator, defmacro and setMacro

Tags: clojure, function

In looking through the clojure.core file after the `defmacro` definition you come to the following code:

```
(. (var defmacro) (setMacro))
```

What does this mean and do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of `.` is as explained by Joost's and Jeremy's answers. In case you're wondering about the details of what is accomplished by this particular method call:

This basically inserts a key called `:macro` with the value `true` into the metadata map of the Var whose name is `clojure.core/defmacro`. The effect of this is that from this point on, if the compiler encounters the symbol `defmacro` in a context where it resolves to the var `#'clojure.core/defmacro` (`#'foo` is shorthand for `(var foo)`) -- which will normally be everywhere, though you could e.g. shadow this Var with a `let`-bound local variable -- it will know that it should treat it as appropriate in the case of a name of a macro.

(Which is to say, either (1) expand the macro call using the function bound to `#'clojure.core/defmacro` if the symbol `defmacro` occurs in the operator position, i.e. immediately to the right of an opening paren, or else throw an exception to complain about a macro name being mentioned in non-operator position.)

Incidentally, the Clojure compiler routinely makes this sort of use of metadata maps on Vars, e.g. to decide on the types of various objects (cf. `:tag` metadata) or whether to inline a function call (IIRC, `:inline` and `:inline-arities`).

Answer (score 2):

I'll break down the entire line, as I don't know what you already know.

First, the [documentation for `var`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#var) says:

> The symbol must resolve to a var, and the Var object itself (not its value) is returned.

If we type this into a REPL we get:

```
user=> (var defmarco)
#'clojure.core/defmacro
```

Now, the `.` special form allows you to [call methods on instances of Java objects](http://clojure.org/java_interop#dot). In this case, the [`setMacro` method](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f86db9cc68773dd3e4a166c1ff7b81e4a98aa602/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L184) on the returned `Var` object is being called.

I am not familiar enough with the code to really understand what `setMacro` is doing, but I gather it is altering the state of the var to say that it is a macro, and not a function or something else.

Answer (score 1):

(. foo (bar)) is the low-level equivalent of (.bar foo), so this calls the method setMacro on the defmacro var with no arguments.

I suspect this call marks the defmacro function/var as being a macro. In general, lots of stuff in clojure.core uses low-level tricks to bootstrap the language so while it's interesting to see how stuff is build up, it's not really a good source for idiomatic code.

Comment: To state the second paragraph in a different way, if you find yourself thinking about you need to call (.setMacro) in your own code, you are almost certainly wrong.